# python django send_mail does not work since smtp servers not supported

Tags: python, qmail

I first tried to use django send_mail function in my python code.

But my live servers does not support SMTP and hence i was asked to try using qmail-inject or mail which are unix commands.

Has anyone does this before ? how can we set the subject, recipient etc from python code and send a email using qmail-inject or mail which are unix commands?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a [custom email backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/?from=olddocs#defining-a-custom-email-backend) that does the sending for you. You can customize [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1864/), which uses `sendmail` and replace that with the appropriate command for your scenario.

Once you have your custom backend, set `EMAIL_BACKEND` in `settings.py` to point to the *Python module path* **not** the filesystem path.